# Helm charts creating from python API

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there any python API to create Helm Charts, which included values.yaml, deployment and service.yaml and other YAML

My use case, I will get have different images and environment variable,  on the fly we need to create the chart and deploy the application

Comment: I don't think there's a code interface to Helm charts beyond what's defined in the Go API.  If the applications are similar enough, you might be able to create a single chart where you can specify the image and environment settings at install time; the template format is involved enough that I probably wouldn't try to programmatically create the files.

Comment: Does that mean you are not familiar with what `--set` or `--values` does in Helm?

Comment: regarding set and values, i should be knowing all fields key a head, but my case I will be getting each deployment different Image URL, and different key values for the environment , So I am thinking to  build values.yaml and template on the values or should have something else to achieve this

Comment: Changing the image repository and/or tag is one of the primary use cases for `--set`, but your question is at risk of closure because you have posted a wishlist, with no code nor error messages from your own attempt at doing that

Answer (score 0):

You can try invoking [Move2Kube](https://konveyor.io/move2kube/) using [os.system](https://janakiev.com/blog/python-shell-commands/) calls to generate the helm chart for your applications.

To make Move2Kube run non-interactively, you can use `move2kube translate --qaskip -s src/`